# How to pause SignedInArgs, move to a page, then continue OR create a new SignedInArgs to complete the login?

Tags: identity-server, authentication

I've created a two-factor page for sitecore login on older sitecore (9.0 and below) by playing with its LoggedInArgs like this:

1. Check the condition if 2FA needed. If it is, then abort LoggedInArgs

`loggedInArgs.AbortPipeline();`

2. On 2FA page the user will enter their code then proceed to login by creating new LoggedInArgs using username and starturl gathered by first step

   ```
   LoggedInArgs loggedInArgs = new LoggedInArgs()
   {
       Username = userName,
       StartUrl = startUrl
   };
   Pipeline.Start("loggedin", loggedInArgs);
   ```
3. Then Sitecore will login accordingly

But on Sitecore 9.1 we are using `IdentityServer` and using new args which is `SignedInArgs`. I can't create the `args` manually since it needs `CookieResponseSignedInContext` from (I guess) `Owin` on `IdentityServer`.

`LoggedInArgs` is deprecated but still usable until Sitecore 9.2 which will delete all deprecated codes.

Is there any way to do it? or some workarounds?

Comment: Are you intending on providing your _own_ 2FA service? Or are you integrating with a federated authentication service like Azure AD or similar?

Comment: @RichardSeal yea. This is my custom 2fa using totp